# Error en Metodo Post en JavaScript usando Fetch

Tags: javascript, post, react-native

Estoy tratando de realizar un Post para mandar una Push Notification mediante Expo, esto para una aplicación desarrollada en React native, lo estoy realizando desde Javascript y me manda este error

Failed to load https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://expo.io' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:62697' is therefore not allowed access. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

lo subi a mi servidor donde tengo alojada mi pagina pero me manda el mismo error
este es el codigo

```
const config = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {

        Accept: "application/json",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },

    body: JSON.stringify({
        "to": "ExponentPushToken[omijKxCLlMs4A_jQn10rnV]",
        "sound": "default",
        "body": "Prueba post"
    })
};


fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", config)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        //console.log(res)
        //return res.secure_url
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        //console.log(err)
    })
```

Comment: Tienes un problema con CORS: ese API está diseñada pensando en que tu servidor haga peticiones, no una aplicación desde un navegador, por lo que no implementa CORS y no podrás leer las respuestas

Comment: Gracias.. al parecer solo bastaba con agregar  mode: "no-cors",  en la constante de configuracion.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer bastaba con agregar

```
    **mode: "no-cors"**,
    method: 'POST',
    headers:
```